# SwiftUI how can I modify @AppStorage variable in a separate window?

Tags: swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and swift programming, and I have a question about how to modify an @AppStorage property.

I'm trying to program an app with an onboarding process, so that it shows several views to the user the first time the app is opened, and from then on, it goes straight to the primary view.

Here is my code in ContentView:

```
@AppStorage("onboardingView") var onboarding = true
    
    var body: some View {
        if onboarding {
            Welcome()
        }
        else {
            PrimaryView()
        }
    }
```

The Welcome() view is a NavigationView, and there's a series of views that it will take you through via navigation links. At the end of the chain, the last view has a button whose action is: UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "onboardingView").

I had expected this to work, since I read that @AppStorage writes to UserDefaults.standard, but the onboarding view appears every time.

How may I be able to make it so that the @AppStorage onboarding variable is set to false in a separate view?

Answer (score 2):

Here: with Binding you can do it.

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("onboardingView") var onboarding = true
    
    var body: some View {
        if onboarding {
            WelcomeView(onboarding: $onboarding)
        }
        else {
            PrimaryView(onboarding: $onboarding)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
    
    @Binding var onboarding: Bool
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
            
            Text("WelcomeView").padding().background(Color.red).cornerRadius(10.0)
            Button("update onboarding to true") { onboarding = true }
            Button("update onboarding to false") { onboarding = false }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct PrimaryView: View {
    
    @Binding var onboarding: Bool
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 20.0) {
            
            Text("PrimaryView").padding().background(Color.yellow).cornerRadius(10.0)
            Button("update onboarding to true") { onboarding = true }
            Button("update onboarding to false") { onboarding = false }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the same

```
@AppStorage("onboardingView") var onboarding
```

into that *end-of-the-chain* view and modify it directly

```
  var body: some View {
     ...
     onboarding = false
     ...
  }
```

*Note: make sure you modify this setting being on main queue*